# Alterar valor de variável de session Laravel

Tags: session, laravel-5.5

Estou com um problema em como alterar a variável de sessão no Laravel. Quando o usuário loga, algumas variáveis são setadas na sessão, uma delas é o nome do usuário. Em um determinado formulário, existe a opção de alterar os dados do usuário, caso ele altere o nome, o valor que estava setado na sessão deve ser alterado mas eu não sei como faz isso.

```
session(
         [
          'id_usuario' => $usuario[0]->id_user,
          'usuario' => $usuario[0]->nome
         ]
);
```

Como eu altero o campo usuario do array da sessão?

Answer (score 0):

Como está a fazer já muda o nome do usuário na sessão. Se quiser mudar/definir apenas o nome pode fazer:

```
session(['id_usuario' => 'novo nome do usuario aqui']);
```

Se está a ler o nome do formulário precisa de utilizar `$request->input` e especificando o campo do formulário que tem o nome:

```
session(['id_usuario' => $request->input('nome')]);
```

O `nome` neste ultimo exemplo corresponde ao atributo `name` do campo do formulário que tem o nome:

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="text" name="nome"/>
    <!-- Corresponde a ------^  -->
```

Outra alternativa seria utilizando o método `put`:

```
$request->session()->put('id_usuario', $request->input('nome'));
```

[Documentação para o Session em Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session)

Comment: Pois é Isac, quando atualizo a página, a sessão é encerrada, dessa maneira, sem contar que se eu fizer dd(session('blabla')) ela retorna null.

Comment: @FelipePaz e `dd(session()->all());` e `dd($usuario)` dão o que ?

Comment: Simplesmente dá null para todo os dados da sessão.

Comment: @FelipePaz e `dd($usuario)` dá o que ?